# Weird and pixelated image on Nvidia control panel

Tags: graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, pixels

I don't know if this is the correct place to post this question if no please guide me where I should post it to get help.

Suddenly my Nvidia GeForce started to give this weird image on the control panel (screenshot below).

My laptop is Lenovo Ideapad s510p and the GeForce is 820M.

I  updated the driver with no luck.

Does anyone know what may be the issue? Is my GeForce dead?

[image]

Comment: Did you update the driver using the Lenovo System Update tool or download from Nvidea site?

Comment: I download it from Nvidea site

Comment: Use Lenovo System Update app to upgrade.  While it is an Nvidea chipset, Lenovo may have made some "tweaks".  The app works very well.

Comment: i did and i received that there is not update available

Comment: Was this problem coincident with some Windows update, software installation or similar?

Comment: Hey there, you should be using the legacy driver as your GPU, based on Fermi's GF108 core is discontinued and relegated to legacy support status. The latest driver available to you is R391.35, released on 27th March 2018: https://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/132842/en-us

Comment: The above is incorrect. There is a new [820M driver](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/145874/en-us). Please answer my above question. And does this happen with other programs?

Comment: it does happen with other programs yes I see disturbing images in other programs as well

Comment: Was this problem coincident with some Windows update, software installation or similar?

Comment: No, it happened suddenly when I was playing a game.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that you have a hardware problem.

Try another graphical card, if you have one available, or visit a repair-shop